# Lambda faster way for variable numbers of different Ids on search

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool> expressionPerfil = Perf =>
  foreach(int _key in Keys){
    Perf.Id == _key ||
  }
```

(I need multiple OR `||`)

I think this is faster than

```
    List<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo> teste = new List<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo>();
    teste.add(context.Find(Id));
```

Possible?

Comment: could you provide more context?

Comment: You can investigate the Secification pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like:

```
//use a method because use a foreach in a lambda expression isn't allowed
public bool myFunction(vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo Perf){
   foreach(int _key in Keys){
        if(Perf.Id == _key || /*other condition here*/)
           return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

And:

```
Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool> expressionPerfil = Perf => myFunction(Perf);
```

Or just:

```
Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool> expressionPerfil = Perf => Keys.Any(_key => Perf.Id == _key || /*other condition here*/);
```

---

> I think this is faster than
>
> teste.add(context.Find(Id));

In this case `context.Find(id)` (where context is a `List<>`) returns the found element while the previous code returns a boolean because of `Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool>`

Comment: Keys.Any, so great, I will test tomorrow, so give a feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I get vacation but The keys.Any Wokrs very well!!
But about the first one, the return have problems, I tried create a list of bools, but need cast only to one... so I cant make whit this first form, look the problem is return act only one time. thanks! Problem solved whit second choice.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was my mistake. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can the `PredicatorBuilder` class. It is a famous class about some extensions methods for lambda expressions. Take a look at this link:

http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

After adding this class at yoru project you can do something like:

```
var result = list.Where(x => condition).And(x => condition).Or(x => condition).ToList();
```